# Error while loading CNN tensorflow model with OpenCV 3.4

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tensorflow

I am currently trying to load a U-net like tensorflow model with OpenCV. The model is created, trained and frozen with Python 3.6.8 using Tensorflow 1.12.0  and I'm trying to load it with OpenCV (3.4.2) in C++ (right now I'm testing loading the model with OpenCV in Python in an analogous way to what I'll do in C++).

I'm using this ( https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet ) implementation of U-net. The graph I have of the trained model looks like this:

[Full model graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH1fH.png)

After I have a trained model I freeze it with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

# Freeze the graph
save_path=".../Unet/unet_trained/run_016/" #directory to model files
input_graph_path = save_path+'graph.pbtxt'#complete path to the input graph
checkpoint_path = save_path+'model_epoch99.ckpt' #complete path to the model's checkpoint file
input_saver_def_path = ""
input_binary = False
output_node_names = "output_map/output" #output node's name
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_frozen_graph_name = save_path+'frozen_model_.pb' # the name of .pb file you would like to give
clear_devices = False

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                      input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,
                      restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,
                      output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices, "")
```

The next step I take is to run the following commands on the terminal:

```
python3 strip_unused.py --input_graph frozen_model_run16.pb 
    --output_graph strip_model_run16.pb --input_node_names x
    --output_node_names output_map/output --input_binary True --output_binary True
```

and

```
python3 optimize_for_inference.py --input strip_model_run16.pb 
    --output optimized_model_run16.pb --frozen_graph True --input_names x
    --output_names output_map/output
```

(Optional) Finally, in order to visualize the graph in tensorboard I run:

```
python3 import_pb_to_tensorboa.py --model_dir optimized_model_run16.pb
    --log_dir unet_trained/frozenmodel/
```

The optimized model graph looks like this:

[Optimized model graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4xSN.png)

[Preprocessing block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rJFU.png)

[DownConvolution block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8jj.png)

[UpConvolution block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6rnI.png)

After all this I try to load this model with OpenCV by doing:

```
import cv2
tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("/path/to/model/frozenmodel/
    optimized_model_run16.pb")
```

However I get this error

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:520: error: (-2:Unspecified error) More than one input is Const op in function 'getConstBlob'
```

and I can't find a solution or an explanation to solve it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

If I load the model this way (adding the .pbtxt file)

```
tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("/home/dev/optimized_model_run16.pb", "/home/dev/graph.pbtxt")
```

I get a different error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:613: error: (-215:Assertion failed) const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second in function 'addConstNodes'
```

Comment: There are problems with preprocessing block. After optimize_for_inference.py it must be linear

Comment: What kind of problem are there? Could you detail a little bit more please? @Nuzhny

Comment: I'm guessing you are passing a `layer` where you should be passing a `tensor`.

Comment: I just tried to load the model in OpenCV without the preprocessing block (I create the batch array with numpy and feed it to the first convolution block) and the error persists @SusmitAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with using tf.shape and tf.stack in deconv2d block [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbz4k.png) (probably because of strided_slice operations). **I can use this model to train and inference on tensorflow**.

However, in order to successfully **load it in OpenCV I had to remove these operations** since they are not yet supported [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KMSa.png). As can be seen in the image, I created the deconv_output_size tensor (previously created by tf.stack) manually. This way this tensors are constant and are not dynamically created inside the tensorflow graphs as before.

I also got rid of the preprocessing block by doing the same operations with numpy outside tensorflow.

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers!